# Play audio on swipe SAFARI IOS 17

Tags: audio, safari, swipe, gesture, audiocontext

I would like to play an audio buffer on a swipe gesture in Safari Mobile.

Seems Safari mobile iOS 17 dropped all support for unlocking audio on events other then a click event or touch (without movement).
Please see this codepen.
`-    https://codepen.io/drizzt22/pen/wvRENxM`    .

Any workarounds?